# Dynasty can't connect to Dynamodb Local - SL3_GET_RECORD wrong version number

Tags: node.js, ssl, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to connect to Dynamodb local with Dynasty and I am getting the following error:

```
There was an error creating the table Error: write EPROTO 140735247142912:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:362:
work@mac ~/d/b/app>
```

This is how I am running Dynamodb local:

```
work@mac ~/d/t/dynamodb_local_2016-05-17> java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8080
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8080
InMemory:   false
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *
```

I can connect using the aws-sdk, but I can't connect through Dynasty.

Here is the code:

```
const credentials = {
        accessKeyId: "<ACCESS_KEY>",
        secretAccessKey: "SECRET_KEY",
        region: "eu-west-1"
    };

const dynasty = require("dynasty")(credentials, "localhost:8080");

const tableOptions = {
    key_schema: {
            hash: ["mobile", "string"],
            range: ["id", "string"]
        },
    throughput: {
        write: 10,
        read: 10
    }
};

dynasty.create("Team", tableOptions)
    .then((response: any) => {
        console.log("The table was created");
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
        console.log("There was an error creating the table", err.stack);
    });
```

I have tried searching for a solution without success, I hope someone here can point out what I am missing...